# I want to count the number of strings in char* word_list[] (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I'm programming hangman.

Question words are saved in char word_list[], const strings.

```
word_list[] = {"apple", "computer", ..., "mouse"};
```

Question is randomly selected from `word_list[]`, and when I use random function I want to know the number of strings in `word_list[]`.

`word_list` is the pointer of `char*`, right?

Finally, how can I know the number of strings in `word_list[]`??

Comment: if this is c++ why not use `string word_list[]`

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the number of characters in the randomly selected string?

Comment: @corn3lius: Because the list would be immutable, so using `string` would make it harder by requiring runtime initialization. The optimal declaration here would be `const char* word_list[] = {"apple", "computer", ..., "mouse"};`

Comment: @MikeDeSimone It looks like he is initializing once at run time any way. what is the difference? also `int count = sizeof(word_list)/sizeof(string);` looks pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Because only C++11 allows an array of objects to be initialized with other than the default constructor. `std::string word_list[] = { "apple", "computer", ..., "mouse"};` doesn't compile without C++11. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `word_list[]` is declared like your code snippet you can obtain the number of elements by doing:

```
const size_t word_count = sizeof(word_list) / sizeof(word_list[0]);
```

You might consider a more flexible method like reading a `std::vector` of `std::string` at run time. That would allow you to modify the word list without having to recompile and the `vector::size()` function would tell you the number of elements.

Comment: It's a hardcoded list, so `std::vector` and `std::string` buy you nothing. Were the word list read from a file, those classes would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll consider using vector or string.

Answer (score 1):

For an initialized array as you have defined, you can use the C method to determine the number of elements in the array. This method uses the `sizeof` operator to find the total size of the array object, and then divides that value by the size of an element of the array.

```
const char * word_list[] = { "a", "b", "c" };

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(word_list)/sizeof(word_list[0]); ++i) {
    // do something
}
```

If `word_list` had been an STL `vector` instead, you could have used the `size()` method on the container.

Comment: You could also use `sizeof(word_list) / sizeof(const char*)`.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, +1. But the advantage of `word_list[0]` is that it will still work if the array of `const char *` is changed to array of `std::string`.

Comment: IIRC, `std::string` wouldn't compile unless you had a C++11 compiler, and I'm not sure the syntax is the same even then. Anyway, I prefer the other route because some programmers are thrown off by `sizeof(not_a_type_or_array_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

`word_list` should be `char* []` (array of char pointer). Since it is an array, you can obtain the size by `sizeof (word_list) / sizeof(word_list[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the strings hard coded, you should really hard code the number of strings too.

```
char* word_list[] = {"apple", "computer", "mouse"};
int words = 3;
```

Comment: That is a really poor idea. Try maintaining that in a huge program.

Comment: Yes, the point of the question is how to avoid having to manually count the number of strings.